# Shopping Cart Delete List To Also Update Total Price

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, shopping-cart

I am using JavaScript to make a website with a shopping cart system. I have made most of the shopping cart and succeeded pretty well after following YouTube videos (considering my noob skills). However, I don't seem to be able to make the functionality of deleting a product list from the cart while also updating the cart.

Here is my JavaScript code to remove the product list from the cart that doesn't update the total price:

```
const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-product')
removeBtn.forEach (function (rBtn) {
    rBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        cartItem.remove();
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem? It would be very appreciated to have an answer...

Here is my HTML, CSS, and the rest of my JS:

HTML:

```
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="main-nav">

        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="index.html" class="logo-link">
            <div class="logo animated fadeInLeft">
                <img src="../Media/Logo/logo-red.png" class="red">
                <img src="../Media/Logo/logo.png" class="normal">
            </div>
        </a>

        <!-- Desktop/ Normal Navigation Links -->
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="animated fadeInRight">
                <a href="shop-creator.html">Creator</a>
            </li>
            <li class="animated fadeInRight">
                <a href="shop-men.html">Men</a>
            </li>
            <li class="animated fadeInRight">
                <a href="shop-women.html">Women</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- All Smaller Icons Here -->
        <div class="nav-small">

            <!-- Search and Shop Icon-->
            <ul class="nav-icons">

                <!-- Icons -->
                <li class="animated fadeInRight" id="search-button">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </li>
                <li class="animated fadeInRight" id="cart-button">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"><sup class="item-count">0</sup></i>
                </li>

                <!-- Search Bar -->
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search">

                <!-- Shopping Cart -->
                <div class="shop-cart">

                    <!-- No Products -->
                    <div class="cart-text no-product">
                        <h3> No products in cart. </h3>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Products -->
                    <ul class="cart-list">
                        <!-- List Items Added By Javascript Here -->
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Total Price -->
                    <div class="cart-text total-price">
                        <h3> $0 </h3>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </ul>

            <!-- Mobile/ Burger Navigation Links -->
            <div class="burger animated fadeInRight">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>

     <section class="product-container">
        <div class="product-slider">
            <ul id="slide-1">
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <div class="product-image">
                            <img src="../Media/Clothes/creator/extendedplay.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-text">
                            <h1> Extended Play </h1>
                            <h2> $420.69</h2>
                            <span class="product-button">Add to Cart</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <div class="product-image">
                            <img src="../Media/Clothes/creator/heartache.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-text">
                            <h1> Heartache </h1>
                            <h2> $999.99</h2>
                            <span class="product-button">Add to Cart</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                ... 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
/* Navigation Bar */

.main-nav {
    display: flex;   
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: fit-content;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    transition: ease-in 0.1s;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: #d3d3d3 solid 1px;
    padding: 20 0;
}

/* Logo */

.logo {
    width: 130px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    outline: none;
}

.logo img {
    width: 100px;
}

.red {
    display: none;
}

.normal {
    display: block;
}

.logo:hover .red {
    display: block;
}

.logo:hover .normal {
    display: none;
}

/* Desktop Navigation Links */

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
    transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}

.nav-links li:first-child {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.nav-links li:last-child {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.nav-links li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: black;
    user-select: none;
}

.nav-links li a:hover {
    color: rgb(196, 8, 8);
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

/* Nav Small */

.nav-small {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/* Nav Icons */

.nav-icons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 5vw;
}

.nav-icons li {
    list-style: none;
    transition: ease-in 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-icons li:hover {
    color: rgb(196, 8, 8);
}

.nav-icons li:first-child {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

.nav-icons li:nth-child(2) {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.nav-icons input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 157.813;
    right: 30;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100vw);

    width: 350px;
    padding: 15 20;
    outline: none;
    border: #d3d3d3 solid 1px;
    transition: ease-in 0.1s;
}

.nav-icons input::placeholder {
    font-size: 13;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: #222;
}

#cart-button i sup {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: white;
    background-color: #222;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 2 7;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin-left: -7;
    top: -1.3em;
    transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}

#cart-button i:hover > sup {
    background-color: rgb(196, 8, 8);
}

/* Shopping Cart List */

.shop-cart {
    position: absolute;
    top: 157.813;
    right: 30;
    transform: translateX(100vw);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 400px;
    max-height: 480px;
    padding: 15 20;
    outline: none;
    border: #d3d3d3 solid 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: ease-in 0.1s;
}

.cart-list {
    height: fit-content;
    max-height: 1000px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.cart-list li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: default;
    padding-right: 20;
}

.cart-img {
    width: 70px;
    margin-right: 30;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.cart-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 15;

    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: #222;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.cart-text h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #222;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.cart-text h3:hover {
    color: rgb(196, 8, 8);
}

.cart-text p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #222;
    cursor: text;
}

.cart-text p span {
    margin: 0 5;
}

.cart-text p span:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.cart-text .x {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.remove-product {
    margin-left: 30;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #222;
}

.remove-product:hover {
    color: rgb(196, 8, 8);
}

.no-product {
    margin-top: 10;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.no-product h3 {
    user-select: auto;
}

.no-product h3:hover {
    color: #222;
    cursor: text;
}

.total-price {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    margin-top: 10;
    padding-top: 20;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.total-price h3 {
    user-select: auto;
}

.total-price h3:hover {
    color: #222;
    cursor: text;
}

.price {
    font-weight: normal;
}

@keyframes slide {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(500px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

/* Burger Navigation Links */

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    width: 50px;
}

.line {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px ;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: 4px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    transition: ease 0.5s;
}

.burger:hover .line {
    background-color: rgb(196, 8, 8);
}

.burger:hover .line:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: -5px;
}

.burger:hover .line:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 3px;
    width: 30;
}

.burger:hover .line:nth-child(3) {
    width: 20;
    margin-left: -3px;
}
```

JS:

```
// Cart Slides in on Button Click

    const cartButton = document.querySelector("#cart-button");

    body.addEventListener("click", () => {

        // On Body Click, Make Shopping Cart Dissapear
        shopCart.style.animation = "";

    });

    cartButton.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {

        // Cart Button Click SLides In Shopping Cart
        if (shopCart.style.animation === "") {
            shopCart.style.animation = "slide 0.3s ease-in forwards";
        } else {
            shopCart.style.animation = "";
        }

        // Remove Search Bar
        searchBar.style.animation = "";

        // Stop Body Clicl From Interrupting
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });

    shopCart.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
        // Stop Body Clicl From Interrupting
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });  

// Add Items To Cart On Button Click

    (function () {

        // Adding the Product Item
        const cartBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".product-button");
        cartBtn.forEach (function (btn) {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

                // Fetch Image 
                let fullPath = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[0].src;
                let pos = fullPath.indexOf("Niels") + 5;
                let partPath = fullPath.slice(pos);

                // Fetch Product Name
                let productName = event.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.textContent;

                // Fetch Product Cost
                let productCost = event.target.previousElementSibling.textContent;
                let finalPrice = productCost.slice(2).trim();

                // Initialize Item Description
                const item = {};
                    item.img = `..${partPath}`;
                    item.name = productName;
                    item.price = finalPrice;

                // Create the List Item
                const cartItem = document.createElement('li');
                cartItem.classList.add('product-cart-item');
                cartItem.innerHTML = `
                    <img src="${item.img}" alt="" class="cart-img">
                    <div class="cart-text">
                        <h3> ${item.name} </h3>
                        <p class="price">$${item.price}</p>
                    </div>
                    <i class="fas fa-times remove-product"></i> 
                `;

                // Insert Product Item Into Cart as a List Item
                const cartList = document.querySelector('.cart-list'); 
                cartList.appendChild(cartItem); 
                alert('Item added to cart.');

                // Remove Product List on Remove Button Click -- !DOES NOT WORK! --
                const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-product')
                removeBtn.forEach (function (rBtn) {
                    rBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        cartItem.remove();
                    });
                }); 

                // Update Total
                showTotals();

            });
        });

        // Showing the Total Price
        function showTotals () {
            const total = [];
            const items = document.querySelectorAll('.price');

            // Fetch Prices As Numbers Into Array
            items.forEach (function (item) {
                itemCartPriceDollar = item.textContent;
                itemCartPrice = itemCartPriceDollar.slice(1); 
                total.push(parseFloat(itemCartPrice));
            }); 

            // Add the Prices
            const totalMoney = total.reduce(function (total, item) {
                  total += item;
                  return total;
              }, 0); 
            const finalMoney = totalMoney.toFixed(2);

            // Display into Total
            document.querySelector('.total-price h3').textContent = `$${finalMoney}`;
            document.querySelector('.item-count').textContent = total.length;
        }

            // Remove "No Products in Cart" Text if there is Products
            let noProduct = document.querySelector('.no-product');
            if (total.length == 0) {
                noProduct.style.display = 'flex';
            } else {
                noProduct.style.display = 'none';
            }
    }) ();
```

Comment: kindly add complete code.

Comment: what complete code do you want me to add? I have edited it to have some more code that is related to the shopping cart (all the other codes are for my other things and it's too much)

Comment: there seems to be no item-count class or div in the hmtl. this is what i meant by complete code. IF there is some code missing, i gets hard to provide a quick solution

Comment: let me add some more code

Comment: also, the item-count class or total-price class can be seen in my added html.

Comment: sorry if i am annoying, first time using stack overflow and have only coded for a few months

Comment: its ok thanks for add the compele  code. Firstly make your total variable global so that it gets updted on every remove function call. and added to the dom as well to display with innerhtml = total;

Comment: changed const total = [ ]; into window.total = [ ]; what else?

Comment: const totalMoney = total.reduce(function (total, item) {
                  total += item; 
                  return total; }, 0); 
            const finalMoney = totalMoney.toFixed(2); is probably the problem (it doesn't consider what happnes if an item is gone), but don't know the solution to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so make the total variable globall so that you can update it on remove and add product case. Then pass to the dom as well to display. Below you can see the working example. Hope it helps :)

```js
//Ad Items To Cart On Button Click
(function () {
let total = [];
let cartItem;
let finalMoney;
    // Adding the Product Item
    const cartBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".product-button");
    cartBtn.forEach (function (btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

            // Fetch Image 
            let fullPath = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[0].src;
            let pos = fullPath.indexOf("Niels") + 5;
            let partPath = fullPath.slice(pos);

            // Fetch Product Name
            let productName = event.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.textContent;
                  
            // Fetch Product Cost
            let productCost = event.target.previousElementSibling.textContent;
            let finalPrice = productCost.slice(2).trim();

            // Initialize Item Description
            const item = {};
                item.img = `..${partPath}`;
                item.name = productName;
                item.price = finalPrice;

            // Create the List Item
            cartItem = document.createElement('li');
            cartItem.classList.add('product-cart-item');
            cartItem.innerHTML = `
                <img src="${item.img}" alt="" class="cart-img">
                <div class="cart-text">
                    <h3> ${item.name} </h3>
                    <p class="price">$${item.price}</p>
                </div>
                <i class="fas fa-times remove-product">remove button</i> 
            `;

            // Insert Product Item Into Cart as a List Item
            const cartList = document.querySelector('.cart-list'); 
            cartList.appendChild(cartItem); 
            alert('Item added to cart.');

            // Remove "No Products in Cart" Text if there is Products
            let noProduct = document.querySelector('.no-product');
            const cartHeight = document.querySelector('.cart-list').offsetHeight;
            if (cartHeight >= 79) {
                noProduct.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                noProduct.style.display = 'flex';
            }

            // Remove Product List on Remove Button Click -- !DOES NOT WORK! --
            const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-product')
            removeBtn.forEach (function (rBtn) {
                rBtn.addEventListener('click', removeCartItems);
            })
           
            // Update Total
            showTotals();

        });
    });

  function removeCartItems(e){
    let selectedItem = event.target.parentElement;

 finalMoney= (total)?(finalMoney -total.pop()).toFixed(2): 0;
    
    //Display Total Cart Items
    document.querySelector('.item-count').textContent = total.length;
    
    //Display into Total
    document.querySelector('.total-price h3').textContent = `$${finalMoney}`;

    selectedItem.remove();
  }

  // Showing the Total Price
  function showTotals () {
    total = [];
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.price');

    // Fetch Prices As Numbers Into Array
    items.forEach (function (item) {
      itemCartPriceDollar = item.textContent;
      itemCartPrice = itemCartPriceDollar.slice(1); 
      total.push(parseFloat(itemCartPrice));
    }); 

    // Add the Prices
    const totalMoney = total.reduce(function (total, item) {
      total += item;
      return total;
    }, 0); 
    finalMoney = totalMoney.toFixed(2);

    // Display into Total
    document.querySelector('.total-price h3').textContent = `$${finalMoney}`;
    document.querySelector('.item-count').textContent = total.length;
  }

}) ();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Website Project</title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
/* Navigation Bar */


</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="main-nav">

        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="index.html" class="logo-link">
            <div class="logo animated fadeInLeft">
                <img src="../Media/Logo/logo-red.png" class="red">
                <img src="../Media/Logo/logo.png" class="normal">
            </div>
        </a>

        <!-- Desktop/ Normal Navigation Links -->
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="animated fadeInRight">
                <a href="shop-creator.html">Creator</a>
            </li>
            <li class="animated fadeInRight">
                <a href="shop-men.html">Men</a>
            </li>
            <li class="animated fadeInRight">
                <a href="shop-women.html">Women</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- All Smaller Icons Here -->
        <div class="nav-small">

            <!-- Search and Shop Icon-->
            <ul class="nav-icons">

                <!-- Icons -->
                <li class="animated fadeInRight" id="search-button">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </li>
                <li class="animated fadeInRight" id="cart-button">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"><sup class="item-count">0</sup></i>
                </li>

                <!-- Search Bar -->
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search">

                <!-- Shopping Cart -->
                <div class="shop-cart">

                    <!-- No Products -->
                    <div class="cart-text no-product">
                        <h3> No products in cart. </h3>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Products -->
                    <ul class="cart-list">
                        <!-- List Items Added By Javascript Here -->
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Total Price -->
                    <div class="cart-text total-price">
                        <h3> $0 </h3>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </ul>

            <!-- Mobile/ Burger Navigation Links -->
            <div class="burger animated fadeInRight">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>

     <section class="product-container">
        <div class="product-slider">
            <ul id="slide-1">
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <div class="product-image">
                            <img src="../Media/Clothes/creator/extendedplay.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-text">
                            <h1> Extended Play </h1>
                            <h2> $420.69</h2>
                            <span class="product-button">Add to Cart</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="product-item">
                        <div class="product-image">
                            <img src="../Media/Clothes/creator/heartache.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-text">
                            <h1> Heartache </h1>
                            <h2> $999.99</h2>
                            <span class="product-button">Add to Cart</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                ... 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just checked it, it worked in updating the item count, however it did not update the total price... How can solve this? TYSM for that btw, very helpful step.

Comment: same thing . make price variable global and in remove function pop it and add to dom wtih innertext as well.

Comment: how do you do that, i put my finalMoney constant as global?

Comment: i am soo nub at javascript sryy

Comment: TYSM OMG! Ur a savior, it works now and I have learned some things. TYYY

Comment: happy to help :)